# get cluster information using system.local and system.peers table

Tags: cassandra, cql

In 3 node cluster `system.local` will have data about current node, and `system.peers` will have data about only 2 other nodes. My question is:

1. If i access any of these 3 machine, will this two table give all details about a cluster.
2. If machine1(that i was accessing to get cluster info) is down, how can i select other node to get the same information?

Basically i am trying to get cluster info using this two table, is there other way to get cluster info?

Comment: What kind of information do you want to get? Do you want to get it programmatically? If yes, in what language?

Comment: why dont you try nodetool status ?

Comment: but still i am confused with my above two question

Comment: 1. yes you can get local node and it peers node information like ip addresses from these two tables which together gives you all nodes cluster information. 2. If you are connecting through an some driver you can withstand one node failure based on you read consistency.

Comment: `you can withstand one node failure based on you read consistency` Same will not apply if i will use nodetool to get the same info and the target machine is down?